# Java how does Key Event Handling Mechanism(KeyListeners notified) work?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How does application/JVM know which classes if implemented key handling interfaces ? Does it use java Reflections or does it check all the classes for methods ?

How can a application or executing JVM understanding to deliver the user event or call the specific methods on a class that implemented the keylistener interface. Does it look at all the classes if those methods are implemented or how does it know which classes implmented keylistener interface ?

If you dont implement the keylistener Interface for a class but still implmentation all its methods. Do the class still process the user event occurred ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to handle particular kind of events for a screen in your blackberry application, then you will need to create a class that implements the particular event interface and register it with your screen.

e.g if you want to handle key events you will need to create a class that implements the [KeyListener](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/device/api/system/KeyListener.html) interface and add register the KeyListener with your screen.

There is example code in the link.

Note: You can create an inner class or an anonymous class rather than having the Screen class implement the interface

Just creating the methods in your `MainScreen` class but not implementing the interface or registering it, will not work.

Answer (score 1):

to proceess event you are to add listener to event producer (e.g button). after event occured producer will call all registered listeners in a loop, passing event object as param.